# TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable en python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hola Equipo, por favor, me pueden ayudar a identificar el error, no comprendo por que sale el siguiente error en python " TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable"

Comment: La verdad, no tengo idea. Tal vez si agregas un código donde ese error ocurra pueda identificar que pasa. Tengo una sospecha, pero no puedo comprobarla.

Comment: Podrías indicarnos que es el primer argumento que estás pasando al método (BD_PHD), ya que adicional a la información que adjuntas en la imagen no es muy fácil deducir a que se debe el error.